# Get max number from given digit [PHP]

Tags: php, numbers, max, digit

I'm trying to get the max number available from given digit.

For example :

```
$inputDigit1 = 4;
$inputDigit2 = 9;
$inputDigit3 = 1;
```

And the output should be :

```
$outputDigit1 = 9999;
$outputDigit2 = 999999999;
$outputDigit3 = 9;
```

For now this is my code :

```
$output = '';
for ($i=0; $i < $inputDigit; $i++) { 
    $output.='9';
}
$output = (int) $output;
```

But I don't know the proper or simpler way to solve this case without use a loop.

Comment: why dont you make an array instead of using a single string for each value? $inputDigit[1] = 4; $inputDigit2] = 9; $inputDigit[3] = 1;

Comment: dear @Bernhard. I'm using this just for example to explain my case. Haha

Comment: dear @mickmackusa thanks for the reference. I'm don't know if there is a function to produce a repeat string like str_replace before.

Comment: Now you know.  And from now on, you will know that you should search StackOverflow extensively before asking a question.  Often the answer to your question already exists in the MILLIONS of pages here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$string='9';
$repeat=9;
echo str_repeat($string,$repeat);

//output 999999999
```

You can set number of time the input string should be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Without a loop, use [str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
<?php
$inputDigit1 = 4;
echo str_repeat($inputDigit1, $inputDigit1); // 4444
```

Though numbers like 999999999 would cause memory issues.